# convert pyspark groupedData object to spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have to do a 2 levels grouping on a pyspark dataframe. 
My tentative:

```
grouped_df=df.groupby(["A","B","C"])
grouped_df.groupby(["C"]).count()
```

But I get the following error:

```
'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

I guess I should first convert the grouped object into a pySpark DF. But I cannot do that.

Any suggestion?

Comment: why  2 level of grouping is required ? can you post your input and output ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue.  The way I got around it was by first doing a "count()" after the first groupby, because that returns a Spark DataFrame, rather than the GroupedData object.  Then you can do another groupby on that returned DataFrame.

So try:

```
grouped_df=df.groupby(["A","B","C"]).count()
grouped_df.groupby(["C"]).count()
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `DataFrame.groupBy(cols)` returns a `GroupedData` object.  In order to convert a `GroupedData` object back to a `DataFrame`, you will need to use one of the `GroupedData` functions such as `mean(cols) avg(cols) count()`.  An example using your example is:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], schema=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.show()

+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
|  a|  b|  c|
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+

gdf = df.groupBy('C').count()
gdf.show()

+---+-----+
|  C|count|
+---+-----+
|  c|    3|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData

> **pyspark.sql.GroupedData Aggregation methods, returned by
>   DataFrame.groupBy().**
>
> A set of methods for aggregations on a DataFrame, created by
>   DataFrame.groupBy().

You may use an aggregation function as agg, avg, count, max, mean, min, pivot, sum, collect_list, collect_set, count, first, grouping, etc.

Attention to first: this function is an action, it can aaa to you script be slower if you misuse this.

If you have a numeric column you can use aggragation function such as min, max, mean, etc but if you have a string column you may want to use:

```
df.groupBy("ID").pivot("VAR").agg(concat_ws('', collect_list(col("VAL"))))
```

or

```
df.groupBy("ID").pivot("VAR").agg(collect_list(collect_list("VAL")[0]))
```

or

```
df.groupBy("ID").pivot("VAR").agg(first("VAL"))
```